# Can git merge a non-versioned common file to a file in git repo?

Tags: git, merge

I have two common files A and B, now I want to merge file B to file A. Both files are not diff/patch files.

And file A is in a git repository, file B is not version controlled by any VCS.
File A and B have duplicate lines, and I don't expect any duplicate line after merging.

Can I merge file B to file A directly with git? Or it does not rely on git?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are strictly using git then you will have to manually edit file A to include what it's missing from file B then just commit as you would normally. Outside of git, although I've never used one I'm sure there's apps/programs out there to help you merge 2 similar files.

Answer (score 1):

Use some merge tool like P4Merge (the best available free diff and merge tool in my opinion) and give the files to it, then use the merge tool to merge the files.